# Using Php and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I recently joined this forum because I was impressed with the way problems are solved.. And  i hope you guys will be of help..

K..I recently started working on  php and mysql,  and I have been able to create a database, login and sign up form.. I want to create a peer to peer donation website..where members donate to each other..but am faced with this problem currently

How to show user 1 details(name,email, phone number, PayPal details) from the database to user2, user3, user4.

I appreciate your help guys..

Comment: Firstly, we need to see code.. Secondly we need to know what you have tried. Thirdly, we don't know how you're running your PHP to the database.. Mysqli or PDO?

Comment: Welcome to SO, first of all I suggest you to use mysqli with php, and secondly, show us what have you tried yet.

Comment: Welcome No one here is going to write code for you. You need to try yourself and if there is any error within code you can ask here .

Comment: Please read [mcve] and [ask] to ask a better received question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a read through http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp, it's pretty simple to read and understand. You're going to be looking at something like:

```
$select = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM user_table WHERE userID = '1'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select);
$name = $row['name'];
$email = $row['email'];
```

etc
etc

Comment: I want the process to be automated..like new registrars get the details of an earlier registrar.. And so on..Thanks

Comment: SELECT * FROM user_table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1; would give you a random user from your table

Comment: M  trying to create something more like a ponzi scheme.. Where 4 new members donate to one existing member.. So I want the 4 new members to get the profile details of the existing member..

Comment: I know how to select data from a database.. But I want to share my user details among themselves.. Someone sign ups and he donates to someone that registered earlier.. After he donates..he also get four new registrars to donate to him..so to be able to donate, they have to be able to see the details of whom they are donating to.. That's basically the concept.. So I need help setting a limit of 4 new users only to donate to an existing users..each of the 4 user..get donated to by 16 new registrars..I want users to be able to see the details of whom they are donating to..

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you can do something like this...

1. Store all user info in a table by keeping a primary key as user_id.
2. Login user-A to the system by using correct user id & password.
3. Then you want to show USER-B's details to User-A get the user_id of USER-A & make a query to DB for his details & after getting the response you can show that to USER-B.

Answer (score 0):

u mean that one user, must be able to see information of all other existing users ? if u wonna this , u must use session for each user ,then select all info from users table except the value of the current session.

in code it can be something like this :

```
$sess_val = $_SESSION['myuser'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM `user_table` WHERE `session_field`!='$sess_val'";
if($query_run = mysql_query($query)){
   while($fetch_all_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)){
      echo 'this is all info'.$fetch_all_data['name'].' '.$fetch_all_data['email'];
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks..let me explain my question this way..User B,C,D,E registers and immediately meets with UserA details.. Users F,G,H,I registers and meets with user B details, Users J,K,L,M registers and meets with User C details and so on..

Comment: so u must specified that which user must be shown for new user that registered right now . for example u told me user B C D E ,after registeration must see user A detail , so it must be specified that which user meets other, 
B,C,D,E ---> A -----
J,K,L,M ----> B ----- and u must store it in user table , now u must select data that regarded to current session

Comment: Silver..what am trying to do is more like a ponzi scheme.. You know how it works ryt.

Comment: sorry I dont know  ponzi scheme :D :D , but the main approach is something that I told u , u can customize to ur story ...

Comment: **don't** use `mysql` functions, they are deprecated and in PHP7 **removed!** - use `mysqli` or `PDO` - and use **parameterized statements**, depending on where `$_SESSION['myuser']` comes from, this code is vulnerable to **SQL Injection**

Comment: yes of course , It s just a simple code , no security :D thanks for advice :)